# Comparing 2 tables in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Comparing to tables in Laravel. I have this code in my class (model):

```
   public function table1() {
        return $this->hasOne(table1Class::class, 'type', 'bms_id');
    }
    public function table2() {
        return $this->belongsTo(table2Class::class, 'bms_id', 'type');
    }
```

The controller, has something like this:

```
 $type =
       DB::table('table2')
          ->join('table1', 'table1.col_id','table1.col_name')
          ->select('table2.*', 'table1.*')
          ->get();

$dataMerge = $dataMerge->merge($type);
```

In the view, I have:

```
@foreach($data as $item)
    {{$item->type==120}} //this works, no problem
    {{$item->col_name}} //this produces nothing!
@endforeach
```

As you can see, the code stops working when referencing the col_name, any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your join is wrong  `join('table1', 'table1.col_id','table1.col_name')`, you are always using the same table, and I'm not sure if the operator can be ignored, take a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins) to see how to build a query with joins. And... why are you defining models and relationships if you are not going to use it in your queries?

Comment: Why aren't you using relations ? Why are you doing this strange thing ?

Comment: I cant really get the relationships working in view, the tables are always empty